# I get strange results when I access the Sqlitedatabase with Unity C# via XAMPP

Tags: php, sqlite, unity-game-engine, authentication, xampp

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbName="escape_room";
    $user_username = $_POST['Input_user'];
    $user_password = $_POST['Input_pass'];
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Cound not Connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT pass FROM escape_room WHERE user = '".$user_username."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //Get the result and confirm login 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            if($row['pass'] == $user_password){ 
                echo "login success";
                echo $row['pass'];  
            }else{
                echo "password incorrect";
                echo "password is =". $row['pass'];
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "user not found";
        echo "password is =". $row['pass'];}
```

I created a WWWForm in Unity C Script and tried to get the value of Mysqlitedatabase by running Login.php on server XAMPP. However, I could not confirm whether the IDs match or not. Only code written in html language will appear in console.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
      <head>
      <title>Object not found!</title>
     ...
```

What should I do?
Thank you for reading.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
public class gamemanager : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("LoginPanel")]
    public InputField ID;
    public InputField PW;
    [Header("CreateAccountPanel")]
    public InputField New_ID;
    public InputField New_PW;

    public string LoginUrI;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        LoginUrI = "localhost/escape_room/Login.php";
    }


    public void LoginBtn()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoginToDB(ID, PW));
    }

    IEnumerator LoginToDB(InputField username, InputField password)
    {
        Debug.Log(username.text);
        Debug.Log(password.text);

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Input_user", username.text);
        form.AddField("Input_pass", password.text);

        WWW webRequest = new WWW(LoginUrI, form);

        yield return webRequest;
        Debug.Log(webRequest.text);

    }

    public void CreateAccountBtn()
    {

    }
       }
```

+Add)
[ This is what I have implemented in the Unity C script. I have an InputField and I used an AddField method to accept that inputField and pass it to php. In addition, I created a WWW object to allow access to Login.php through the server. At the end, I tested via Debug.Log to see how well the logged-in results would look good. ]

Comment: PHP file containing the code is not found by the server. You might be executing wrong url or file.

Comment: You should really consult a tutorial before proceeding with this project. User input direct to SQL is a red flag, as is plain text passwords. Also why iterate over the result set, isn't there only 1 user per username? If not that is a security problem as well because username `john` could be two people.

Comment: @user3783243 
It has helped a lot. I've changed the code, can this be a better code?


$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);    
if ($numrows == 0)
{
 
 die("ID does not exist. \n");


}

Comment: You can't use `mysql_` functions with `mysqli`. Use `mysqli` everywhere, you're going backwards many years if you go to `mysql_`

Comment: @MilindSingh 
In Unity I declare LoginUrI = 'localhost / escape_room / Login.php' as follows: 
Is this URL wrong?

Comment: Can you run "localhost / escape_room / Login.php" the URL on the browser?

Comment: @MilindSingh Yes I did it.
There was no error except the warning that the input value should be executed from Unity C script.

Comment: let's see your WWWform c# script, I think it only takes a single post and a string value

Comment: @comphonia Added to the text. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. confirm your path on xampp, to be sure that this is your directory path C:\xampp\htdocs\escape_room\Login.php
2. You need to actually post the form from unity first, see code below
3. Debug the php alone without sql to make sure you're getting the correct data. see code.

WWWform

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Networking;
    public class gamemanager : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("LoginPanel")]
    public InputField ID;
    public InputField PW;
    [Header("CreateAccountPanel")]
    public InputField New_ID;
    public InputField New_PW;

    string LoginUrI = "http://localhost/escape_room/login.php";
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }


    public void LoginBtn()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoginToDB(ID, PW));
    }

    IEnumerator LoginToDB(InputField username, InputField password)
    {
        Debug.Log(username.text);
        Debug.Log(password.text);

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Input_user", username.text);
        form.AddField("Input_pass", password.text);

        // Make Post Request
        using (var w = UnityWebRequest.Post(LoginUrI, form))
        {
            yield return w.SendWebRequest();
            if (w.isNetworkError || w.isHttpError) {
                 Debug.Log(w.error);
            }
            else {
                  Debug.Log(w.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }


    }

    public void CreateAccountBtn()
    {

    }
       }
```

Test php code, replace you Login.php with this to make sure you get the values first.

```
<?php


    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
        echo "Successful post"; 
        var_dump($_POST);
    } else die("Error: post not successful");
?>
```

Comment: Generic / unknown HTTP error. 
I am using xampp's server, MySql, and I don't know why I get an error.

Comment: I use both too, not sure why, does it work for other things?

Comment: No. I only ran it on my laptop.

Comment: copy the new C# code, just tested it in unity and its working. the public string was messing it up, I also set it outside of Start()

Comment: you should see the results as a unity debug, without having to go to the browser, so you know its posted

Comment: Wow. You are genius. Why wouldn't I think of that? I have received great grace from you. thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help